# Sort "My SharePoint Sites" list in "My Links"

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Anyone know of any way to get the "My SharePoint Sites" list that is generated and shown in the users's "My Links" to be sorted alphabetically?  They seem to display in a random order by default.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the master page in sharepoint designer can you see the datasource for the list.

Try and set and order by at this level.